# Jasmine Unit Test: should I test the logic or the actual mocked data?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

when performing unit testing is it better to test the literal result that I expect hard-coding it into the test (`expect(x).toBe(17)`), or is it better to test the logic and not the specific mock data that I am using (`expect(x).toBe(mockedData.value)`)

The first approach seems safer because I am sure that the test is actually testing the literal result that I expect, however the second approach is more flexible since it allows me to test the logic rather than worry about the mock data (which I can also change later without having to rewrite the test itself)

What are the advantages/disadvantages of either approach? What is the best practice in these cases?

Following is a quick example:

```
// MockedData is a very long array of complex objects 
// each of them has a property 'value' of type number 
import mockedData from 'data.mock';

class ClassToTest {
    private data;
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    plusOne(): number {
        return this.data.value + 1;
    } 
}

describe('test', () => {
    let instance: ClassToTest;
    beforeEach(() => {
        instance = new ClassToTest(mockedData[0]);
    })
    it('plusOne() should return the property "value" plus one', () => {
        // Should I write this...
        expect(instance.plusOne()).toBe(mockedData[0] + 1);
        // ...or this?
        expect(instance.plusOne()).toBe(17); // Because I know that mockedData[0].value is 16
    }) 
});
```

Thank you very much!! :)

Comment: This is a great question, unfortunately, it's not a good fit for SO because there's no correct answer, there are arguments for doing it either way. In this case, the method is plusOne, it makes sense to see the assertion being `something +1`. However, in less made up cases, it's often easier to understand what is being tested when you use hardcoded numbers (even if it makes the test more brittle when mock data is changed.

Comment: TBH you do a **input 17 = ouput 17** this is no test. If you do **input  true = ouput  17** then it's a test.
Try testing on component cause your service should always give the expected result if you give the right input. If not your input is wrong or your backend proces is wrong.

Comment: IMO using `mockedData` is more descriptive for this test case, if it were: *16.plusOne should return 17* then I would agree to use the literal. Your assertions should stay close to the spec description

Comment: There are many ways you can test a component and all ways are designed for specific condition. its not like you will use only one way and not another. By the way its knoe you will store the expected result in a file of hard code it. its nothing to do with technique.

Comment: By the way, both your tests are failing ;) you need to call the method

Comment: @JuanMendes you're right, I forgot the parentheses :)

Comment: @Swoox why I shouldn't test my services? I prefer to keep the logic there and avoid too much logic in components and views :) However the real-world test is more complicated and it's about mapping fetched data props with a normalized data interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test you want to test your unit, which in your case is the logic inside of your `plusOne()` function. So you want to only know if something changes inside the function.

The most dangerous path is to use `expect(instance.plusOne()).toBe(17);`, because if someone changes your logic to `return this.data.value + 2;`, you will never spot from test only if the problem is in the function logic or in the mockedData.

The less dangerous approach is to use `expect(instance.plusOne()).toBe(mockedData[0] + 1);`, because this will tell you if the logic in your function change. Still not optimal, since you depend on an external mock to run your test that you don't need. Why would you want to depend on an external mocked data to test your unit?

The best way to test your unit logic here is to do something like this:

```
describe('test', () => {
    let instance: ClassToTest;
    const mockedValue = 1;
    beforeEach(() => {
        instance = new ClassToTest(mockedValue);
    })
    it('plusOne() should return the property "value" plus one', () => {
        expect(instance.plusOne()).toBe(mockedValue + 1);
    }) 
});
```

Then, you can implement separate tests for your service, here you only test the logic inside `plusOne()`.